# hide auto generated assignement operator and copy constructor without replacing them

Tags: c++

I want to publicly hide the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Furthermore i want to provide a `clone()`.

Is it possible to just mark the copy constructor and the assignment operator as `protected` or `private` and use them in the clone function?

Maybe some kind of using clause.

The reason is that the class contains some data and a unique id that should be incremented with every instance. So making a copy would be using the default assignment operator and then change the id. I would like to circumvent the need to copy every member by hand to avoid forgetting to add one if a member was added to class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
class MyClass {
      MyClass(const MyClass&) = default;
      MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = default;
};
```

Comment: at least since C++11

Comment: it seems that my compiler i am bound to, does not understand this aspect of c++11 :-(

Comment: `MyClass()` is not an assignment operator.

Comment: @IInspectable Better?

Comment: Sort of. The OP didn't want to hide the default c'tor. Is there a particular reason you did?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ by declaring a construcor (in this case the copy constructor) the default one is removed anyway, is not? To not hide it you have to put it explicitly into public again.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch As mentioned by others, introducing the default implementations is tantamount to introducing user defined constructors and assignment operations. There won't be a compiler generated default constructor. But you can again create a public default constructor with the same technique as used in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer of πάντα ῥεῖ would be the most favorable if c++11 is available I solved the problem by using a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) object counter that manages the `id`.

This class implements the counter and re-implements the copy c'tor and assignment operator so that the default ones of the child class can be created and used without danger.

```
template <class T>
class UidProvider
{
public:
  UidProvider()
  {m_id = getNewUId();}

  UidProvider(const UidProvider&)
  {m_id = getNewUId();}

  UidProvider& operator= (const UidProvider&)
  {m_id = getNewUId();}

  uint32 id()
  {return m_id;}

private:
  uint32 m_id;

  static uint32 getNewUId(){ return ++sm_id;}
  static uint32 sm_id;
};

class MyClass : public UidProvider<MyClass >{
 // ...
}

// in cpp
uint32 UidProvider<MyClass >::sm_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> hide auto generated assignement operator and copy constructor **without replacing them**

To be pedantic, not possible.

In c++03 absolutely not possible.

In c++11, defining them as `=default` *is technically providing a user-defined* assignment operator and copy constructor, it's just that you're replacing them with the same functions that the compiler would implicitly generate. This will have the same effects as writing them explicitly - i.e. preventing the auto-generation of a move-assignment and a move-constructor.